# Why pysark areaUnderROC is different from sklearn roc_auc_score?

Tags: pyspark, scikit-learn, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I'm running few binary classifications with pyspark and I'm using `BinaryClassificationEvaluator` to evaluate the predictions made on the test set. Why on earth I have different results if I use the sklearn roc_auc_score? For example:

```
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import BinaryClassificationEvaluator
from pyspark.ml.classification import RandomForestClassifier

trainDF, testDF = df.randomSplit([.8, .2], seed=42)
evaluator = BinaryClassificationEvaluator(
    labelCol="label", rawPredictionCol="prediction", metricName="areaUnderROC")

rf = RandomForestClassifier(labelCol="label", featuresCol="features")
rfModel = rf.fit(trainDF)
prediction = rfModel.transform(testDF)

# now in the DataFrame prediction I have those columns: 'label','prediction','probability'
#  +-----+----------+---------------------+
#  |label|prediction|probability          |
#  +-----+----------+---------------------+
#  |0    |0.0       |[1.0,0.0]            |
#  |0    |0.0       |[0.9765625,0.0234375]|
#  |0    |0.0       |[0.9765625,0.0234375]|
#  +-----+----------+---------------------+

areaUnderROC = evaluator.evaluate(prediction) #IT RETURNS 0.954459

#NOW I USE PANDAS
RF_pred = prediction.select('label', 'prediction', 'probability').toPandas()
probRF=[]
for i in range(prediction.count()):
    probRF.append(RF_pred['probability'][i][1])  #it takes only the probability for the label 1 

auc = roc_auc_score(RF_pred['label'], probRF) #IT RETURNS 0.9962
```

How it is possible?

Comment: Post that as an answer, rather than an edit.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: As @BenReiniger correctly points out - please do not answer in the question; post this as an answer and subsequently **accept** it (you'll need to wait 48 hours before being able to do so since you self-answered), so that it can be useful for others in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have used the **probability** column or leave it with the default value I guess!! In this way I have the same value of roc_auc_score. Shouldn't I have an error or something with the wrong column?

```
evaluator = BinaryClassificationEvaluator(
                                         labelCol="label",
                                         rawPredictionCol="probability", 
                                         metricName="areaUnderROC")
```

I hope this will help because there is not much about `BinaryClassificationEvaluator` even in the official documentation, they only use `MulticlassClassificationEvaluator` in their examples